# Insert into mysql

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I want to pass parameters to a batch file which will then inserted into mysql database.

```
lunch.bat name surname

echo off
mysql -uusername -ppassword -e "set @1:=name; set @2:=surname; source insert.sql;"
```

In insert.sql

```
insert into mytable(namecol,surnamecol) values(@1,@2);
```

Someone can help me in writing both scripts?

Thanks

Comment: You should accept your recent questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added single quotes to handle string input... still wobly if quotes are supplied in the paramaters

```
@echo off
mysql -uusername -ppassword -e "set @1:='%1'; set @2:='%2'; source insert.sql;"
```

Done!

Comment: Might wanna quote those to be sure.

Comment: I think we both agree that overall the solution is not waterproof I'm not so sure how quoting will change much about that...you need then to 'unquote' the %1 and %2 vars to be sure no single quote is supplied on the input....

Comment: This is a batch file which accepts @1 parameter at command line.


I:\>mysql --user=root --password=mypassword --host=localhost --database=mytable -e
"set @1:=aaa; source insert.sql;"
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'aaa' in 'field list'

aaa is the parameter
The insert.sql file is:

insert into mytable(data) values(@1);

Comment: it's seems that the the sql command interprets parameter as the name of the column. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of my code that I been working on, although it post to database every time you visit the page. I've tried to add "unique key" with rand() in database. But the code still grabs "rand() on page" and post without "Submit" from form. Anyways this is how I insert data to Mysql. My database creates time and day timestamp() & order by "id."

```
    // Select from database working
    $statement = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM pressroom ORDER BY id 
    DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 30' );
    $statement->execute();
    $count = $statement->rowCount();
    if( $count > 0 ) {
    $R = $statement->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    for( $x = 0; $x < count($R); $x++ ) {
    echo "<td><br>";
    echo "<center><b>" . $R[ $x ]['name'] . "</th>";
    echo ": <left></b>" . $R[ $x ]['comment'] . "</th>";
    echo "<center>" . $R[ $x ]['date'] . "<hr></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
     }
     }

     // Make sure that the 'values' are in the same order or as 
        your table

      $query = "INSERT INTO pressroom(first_name, last_name, Password )
      VALUES ('table1','table2','table3')";

    //connection prepare
    try {
    $database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $results = $database->query($query); 

    //Prints results that are added to table
    print_r($results); 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```